# Does prometheus have a async lib?

Tags: prometheus, aiohttp

I have a service running that uses aiohttp, and I want to monitor it using prometheus but I can not find any "official" libraries that are supported by the prometheus team. Does the prometheus client work for async? or is there a library im missing somewhere? If you have done something similar what did you have success with?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two python modules that does that.

The first one is [aiohttp-prometheus](https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp-prometheus-monitoring/)

> This package allows to monitor availability of your aiohttp-application components and exports the metrics for prometheus scraper.

It natively export three metrics (`request_latency_seconds`, `requests_total`, `requests_in_progress_total`) but you can add your own metrics. It is explained with more details by the maintainer of the module in his [blog post](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/monitoring-your-asynchronous-python-web-applications-using-prometheus), and the [example file](https://github.com/amitsaha/aiohttp-prometheus/tree/master/examples/webapp1) shows a basic aiohttp app, with the corresponding scrape configuration file.
Note that it hasn't been updated since december 2018, so it doesn't support the [Summary](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#summary) metric type and it might not work on the latest versions of aiohttp or prometheus.

The second one is [aioprometheus](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/monitoring-your-asynchronous-python-web-applications-using-prometheus), it's made for the asyncio library, but you can easily use it for aiohttp.

> Examples in the examples/frameworks directory show how aioprometheus can be used within various web application frameworks without needing to create a separate aioprometheus.Service endpoint to handle metrics.

[This file](https://github.com/claws/aioprometheus/blob/d6dec47b05cab04901ffb8d2016d659927e02311/examples/frameworks/aiohttp-example.py) shows a basic example of its use with aiohttp.